# Çinlar Probability and Stochastics, tail-$\sigma$-algebra and Example 5.11

Tags: probability-theory

I am learning Kolmogorov’s 0-1 law, and there are some points I don't really understand about tail-$\sigma$-algebra in one of the examples provided by Çinlar. The ones I have problems with are b) and d).

For b), why is this event $\{\lim \sup \frac{1}{n}S_n > b\}$ unaffected by the first n variables? Is this because of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, so that previous information about $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ is irrelevant?

For d), I don't understand why the information $\{X_n \in B \; i.o.\}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$. Should this be $\{\lim X_n \in B \; i.o.\}$ instead? I can understand that for finite n, $\{X_n \in B \; i.o.\}$ is in all $\mathcal{T}_m$ where $m < n$, because it counts as future information. However, when $m \geq n$, this doesn't count as "future information" anymore, so it shouldn't be in $\mathcal{T}_m$?

Thanks in advance to everyone who's trying to help out :)

Here are the screenshots of the definition and the example from the book:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of (b) is essentially correct.  More precisely, we have
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}S_n = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}(S_n - S_N)$$
and $S_n - S_N$ is $\mathcal{T}_N$-measurable when $n \geq N$.

---

Your explanation of (d), however, would seem to imply a misunderstanding of the notation itself.  When we write $\{X_n \in B \,\, \text{i.o.}\}$, the "i.o." provides a scope for $n$ (one might alternatively read it in this context as "for infinitely many $n$").  In fact, $\{\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n \in B \,\, \text{i.o.}\}$ doesn't even make any sense.  Rather, we have, in addition to the characterization given in the text,
$$\{X_n \in B \,\, \text{i.o.}\} = \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty \{X_k \in B\} = \{\forall n, \exists k \geq n, X_k \in B\}$$
It's definitely "future information", as we may determine whether a point in the sample space lies in this event or not by seeing whether $X_k \in B$ for some $k \geq n$ sufficiently large, for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yep, I definitely wasn't clear about the meaning of "i.o.". Really appreciate that you provided such a thorough explanation!